# Chai expect assertion to.have.string failure: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, firebase, promise, mocha.js

I have a test suite with an instance of firebase-server module, invoked both in the test suite and another separate function.

That is so I can test various test cases with mock values inside my firebase instance.

In my test suite I perform various tests, and they all work as intended until I get to the point where I am testing Firebase promise:

```
Firebase.database().ref('userData').once('value').then((data) => {

    // --- USER ID VALIDATION ---//
    if (!userIds[USER_ID]) {
      throw(`Invalid User ID: ${USER_ID}`);
    }
    updates[`${USER_ID}/sessions/${newSessionKey}`] = event.session;

    // --- UPDATE DATABASE ---//
    Firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
      .then(() => context.succeed('Database Write Successful.'))
      .catch(error => context.fail(`Database Write Error: ${error}`));
})
.catch(error => context.fail(`Database Access Error: ${error}`));
```

by mocking the database content to make my call to my lambda function fail:

```
it( 'should fail invocation with invalid user Id: ', function( done ) {

  var context = {
    succeed: function() {
      done( new Error( 'never context.succeed' ) );
    },
    fail: function( errorMessage ) {
      expect( errorMessage ).to.have.string("Invalid User ID");
      done( );
    }
  }
  dbReset();// resetting database state to valid format
  Firebase.database().ref('userData').set({
    "InvalidFakeUserID" : {
      "apiHits" : 100
    }
  })
  myLambda( event, context );
});
```

Now, I understand that the lambda function is returning an error, but I can't figure how to handle the error assertion on the test side. When I am trying to expect a particular string it passes the test every time, no matter what the string I am expecting. If I expect an error instead:

```
fail: function( errorMessage ) {
      expect( errorMessage ).be.an('error');
      done( );
}
```

it also triggers an error:

`(node:12144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): AssertionError: expected 'Opearlo Analytics --- Database Access Error: Error: Invalid Voice App Name: fakeNameNotPresentOnDB' to be an error`

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: "on the function side"?

Comment: You are right, I guess it is implicit, I am going to amend the wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are successfully provoking the desired error but not handling the error condition properly.

Issue may well arise from the expectation that `error` is always String leading to unexpected throws from your error handling.

Whereas the explicit `` throw(`Invalid User ID: ${USER_ID}`) `` throws `String`, other errors will (or at least *should*) throw `Error`.

In any case, it needs fixing such that only Errors are thrown/expected.

Try :

```
Firebase.database().ref('userData').once('value').then((data) => {
    // --- USER ID VALIDATION ---//
    if (!userIds[USER_ID]) {
        throw new Error(`Invalid User ID: ${USER_ID}`);
    }
    updates[`${USER_ID}/sessions/${newSessionKey}`] = event.session;

    // --- UPDATE DATABASE ---//
    Firebase.database().ref().update(updates)
    .then(() => context.succeed('Database Write Successful.'))
    .catch(error => {
        throw new Error(`Database Write Error: ${error.message}`);
    });
}, error => {
    throw new Error(`Database Access Error: ${error.message}`)
})
// catch whatever Error was thrown, explicitly or otherwise 
.catch(error => context.fail(error.message)); // pass `error.message`, or ...
// .catch(error => context.fail(error));      // ... pass the entire error
```

And, on the test side, write your `expect` expression accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is NodeJS having your back and telling you you have a bug you're not aware of and where the issue is. If you run it with `--trace-warnings` it will also show you the exact line it originated in.

Node is telling you that's you're passing an invalid voice app name to the database. You should fix that or handle the warning in the place you do that.

Again, you can find out the line it happens in with `--trace-warnings`.